# Using OGR2OGR to re-project a shapefile Error

Tags: ogr2ogr

I want to use ogr2ogr command to convert projection of a shapefile. The conversion code is as following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs EPSG:3573 G:\CIS_Sea_Ice_Chart\cis_SGRDRWA_20160606T1800Z_pl_a.shp G:\CIS_Sea_Ice_Chart_3573\cis_SGRDRWA_20160606T1800Z_pl_a.shp
```

However, I encountered am error as Fig.2. I don't know the whether the output shapefile should be established in advance.

```
Unable to open datasource `G:\CIS_Sea_Ice_Chart_3573\cis_SGRDRWA_20160606T1800Z_pl_a.shp' with the following drivers.
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html for the usage.

In your command, `G:\CIS_Sea_Ice_Chart\cis_SGRDRWA_20160606T1800Z_pl_a.shp` is the destination (result), and `G:\CIS_Sea_Ice_Chart_3573\cis_SGRDRWA_20160606T1800Z_pl_a.shp` is the source. The error is saying that the `G:\CIS_Sea_Ice_Chart_3573\cis_SGRDRWA_20160606T1800Z_pl_a.shp` file could not be found.

I think you meant to use the reverse order.